# Chain doesn't support EPI-3855 and broke front end?

Tags: foundry, etherjs

I'm trying for 3 days now to make this work, but i'm always getting these errors:

Deploying to local:

```
EIP-3855 is not supported in one or more of the RPCs used.
Unsupported Chain IDs: 31337.
Contracts deployed with a Solidity version equal or higher than 0.8.20 might not work properly.
```

Using scaffold eth 2 with foundry:

```
InvalidParamsRpcError: Invalid parameters were provided to the RPC method.
Double check you have provided the correct parameters.

URL: http://127.0.0.1:8545
Request body: {"method":"eth_getCode","params":[null,"latest"]}

Details: invalid type: null, expected 20 bytes, represented as a hex string of length 40, an array of u8, or raw bytes
Version: viem@1.19.9
```

Full report from git: https://pastebin.com/fk8XZDGY

Is this a know bug?